# mySQL COLUMNS TERMINATED BY DELETE Character?

Tags: mysql, character, load-data-infile

I am trying to load large text files that are delimited by DEL.  Using Coldfusion I can do chr(127), but that doesn't seem to work here

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\inetpub\\vhosts\\mysite.com\\dataload.data"
INTO TABLE tbl_data
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\0x7F'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I have been searching and trying a number of things that look like they can be DEL characters.  Does anyone have any suggestions for the COLUMNS TERMINATED BY line?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found that my original statement was close.  The answer is:

```
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY X'7F'
```